# Validate the return value of copy_if

Tags: c++

I would like to check if the return value of `std::copy_if` is valid.
Something like this

```
auto it=std::copy_if(s.begin(),s.end(),d.begin(),[&](...){...});
if([it]) // ????
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: What is your question? `it` is "one past the last copied element". So your copied range would be `[d.begin(), it)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `copy_if` marks the "one past the end" of the destination range. If you passed a range to `copy_if` that can hold all of your to-be-copied values then you can dereference everything between the begin of your output range up to `it - 1`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> d(10);

    auto ce = std::copy_if(s.begin(),s.end(),d.begin(),[&](int x){ return x > 5; });

    for(auto i = d.begin(); i != ce; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @Pixelchemist's answer is to erase from the returned iterator to the end of the destination. This leaves behind only those elements that satisfied the condition.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> s{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    std::vector<int> d(10);

    auto it = std::copy_if(s.begin(),s.end(),d.begin(),[&](int x){ return x > 5; });
    d.erase(it, d.end());

    for(int i : d)
    {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`copy_if` returns a pointer one past the element it last copied. So in your case the destination range would be `[d.begin(), it)`.

Not sure what type of error checking you would want to do but you can for example use the pointers to see how many elements were copied:

```
unsigned int elementsCopied = it - d.begin();
```

You can also iterate over the elements copied:

```
for(auto i = d.begin(); i != it; ++i)
{
    //perform action on i
}
```

If you are still unsure about how `copy_if` works, [c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/) gives a clear explanation in my opinion.

Perhaps also interesting, this is a possible implementation of `copy_if` so you can see what is going on:

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
     OutputIterator copy_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                      OutputIterator result, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
    while (first!=last) {
        if (pred(*first)) {
            *result = *first;
            ++result;
        }
        ++first;
    }
    return result;
}
```